# How to define where to start retrieving data with Spring Data Pageable request?

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-data-jpa

Is there a way to aim where to apply a `Page` request with Spring Data? I have some trouble to find suitable solution to this problem:

I have an sql table and I would like to retrieve 3 rows from a given id. I tried something like that :

```
Pageable pageable = new PageRequest( 0, 3, Sort.Direction.DESC, "id_user" );
Page<User> users = userReposiotry.findById_user(20L,pageable);
```

I want to start from 20 to 18 but this gives me only one row. 
How can I achieve that?

I could make an algorithm with a loop to retrieve these data but in some case the `id_user`is not ordering.

If it is not possible with this kind of solution, how would you proceed to retrieve 3 rows (or plus) from a given row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **start row number** is limited by **page size** for `PageRequest`.
Because `Pageable.getOffset()` and `Pageable.getPageSize()` are used to perform a SQL query like `select * from userTable order by id_user limit 3 offset 17`.
`Pageable.getOffset()` return the **start row number**, but it's calculated by `pageNumber*pageSize` in the default implementation.  (@see [AbstractPageRequest](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-commons/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/domain/AbstractPageRequest.java), the super class of `PageRequest`)

If you want to retrieve data by any row number, a solution is creating your own `Pageable`. Here is a sample:

```
import org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Sort;

public class MyPageable implements Pageable {
    private final int offset;//first record is 0
    private final int size;
    private final Sort sort;

    public MyPageable(int offset, int size, Sort sort) {
        if (offset < 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Page offset must not be less than zero!");
        }
        if (size < 1) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Page size must not be less than one!");
        }
        this.offset = offset;
        this.size = size;
        this.sort = sort;
    }

    public int getPageNumber() {
        int page = offset / size;//TBD
        return page;
    }

    public Pageable next() {
        return new MyPageable(offset+size, size, sort);
    }

    public Pageable previousOrFirst() {
        int prevoffset = offset-size;//TBD
        return new MyPageable((prevoffset<0?0:prevoffset), size, sort);
    }

    public Pageable first() {
        return new MyPageable(0, size, sort);
    }

    public boolean hasPrevious() {
        return offset > 0;
    }

    public int getOffset() {
        return offset;
    }

    public int getPageSize() {
        return size;
    }

    public Sort getSort() {
        return sort;
    }
```

`userReposiotry.findById_user(20L, new MyPageable(18-1, 20-18+1, new Sort(Sort.Direction.DESC, "id_user"));` 
will return 18th to 20th rows as you wished.

Comment: I will test it, I have some questions because maybe I misunderstood how `PageRequest`'s constructor works. When we make a `new PageRequest (int page, int size, Sort sort, String properties)` what the 2 first constructor's arguments (`page`and `size`)  represent? In my mind `page` is the number of pages we want and `size` the number of elements in each page, am I right?

Comment: Yes. You should convert **start row number** to **page number** for `PageRequest`. If **start row number** is not divisible by **page size**, you will get unexpected data.